# Java Web Start applications ask repeatedly for un-existing files

Tags: java, java-web-start

All my application I make with NetBeans as a Java Web Start applications behave quite strangely. When I run them as a normal application, everything works.

But when I compile them as java web start apps, they, **after** the java web start is done with loading, repeatedly ask server for libraries on the wrong place. It doesn't seem to matter in small projects, but it makes a huge time difference in large projects (see my first question).

I put a simple NetBeans project [here](http://github.com/runn1ng/awindow). It should paint a window with a button that does nothing at all. (if you try to put it somewhere, upload the `dist` folder somewhere and edit the `.jnlp` file)

You can see from the logs (in logs.txt) that the libs are first downloaded fine from `/awindow_dist/lib/`, but then there comes a lot of requests to the wrong place, `/awindow_dist/`. What can be wrong? Everything seems to be configured fine.

Is it a NetBeans bug? A WebStart bug? Or my fault somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it is definitely a bug in NetBeans, very probably in the build.xml file generated by NB.

I am kind of lost in the giant build.xml and build-impl.xml and jnlp-impl.xml, but my dirty workaround for Java Web Start to work in NetBeans is:

1. copy the generated JNLP somewhere, because it is fine
2. turn **off** the JWS in the NetBeans project
3. instead of letting NetBeans to sign the .jar files, writing some shell script like this

   ```sh
   ant clean
   ant jar 
   #because these two works fine

   for i in `ls dist/*.jar; ls dist/lib/*.jar`
   do
      jarsigner -storepass mystorepass -keypass mykeypass $i myname
      #sign all the .jars
   done

   cp launch.jnlp dist/launch.jnlp 
   #copy the .jnlp
   ```
4. make the script a target in the build.xml like [this](http://sumedha.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-call-shell-script-from-ant.html)

Done. It's a dirty hack and works only with bash, because I don't really know how ant works + the build files, generated by netbeans, are really complicated. But it gets the work done.